# XNA Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, xna, nullreferenceexception

Everything was working fine on this game I am making, but now I started getting NullReferenceException errors on some of my code.

Here I define a Vector2 and a Texture2D:

```
Vector2 startButtonPosition;
Texture2D startButton;
```

And then in the Initialise() method:

```
startButtonPosition = new Vector2((graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - startButton.Width) / 2, 150);
```

When I run this, I get the NullReferenceException error on the startButtonPosition initialisation saying that the object reference was not set to an instance of an object. Yet it is.

Comment: Are `graphics` and `startButton` initialized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Either `graphics` or `startButton`, or one of their properties you are using, is set to null.

You can check this by hovering over the variables when an exception is thrown (Click **break**)

Remember just because you declare `startButton` as a variable, does not mean it is set to a value. You need to initialize it. (Ex: `startButton = Content.Load<Texture2D...`)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is trying to initialize 'startButtonPosition' using 'startButton'. The problem is, you never initialize 'startButton' therefore it is 'null'.

@Pierre-Luc Pineault is right to suggest [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Here's a link to initialize 'startButton'. [Texture2D Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.texture2d.aspx)

I haven't used Texture2D but I'm assuming it'll look something like this:

```
Texture2D startButton = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, width, height);
```